# onKeyDown doesn't work when I click back arrow

Tags: android, android-widget

Can someone explain me how is this possible: I have in code in my main activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { // breakpoint
              // show alert
              return true;
          }
           return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }
```

and it works on HTC but on Samsung it wont enter in this function. I was in debug mode and press back button ( real button, arrow ) but it didn't enter and didn't stop on breakpoint. Can someone give me explanation for this ?

Answer (score 1):

for handling back button you have to override

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //handle back key event
}
```

if you do not want to finish activity on back pressed then 
remove `super.onBackPressed();`

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this ...

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        {       
            keyCode=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1;
            // do here......
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: @lim_939:if he specified that particular thing does not work for him,then why are giving this same in answer again?if you do this then people will downvote you

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: -1 for wrong answer..what about right answer? you should +1 :)

Comment: @Sameer Actually onBackPressed & onKeyDown will do the same functionality in this scenario. so i will +1 if it works for "Damir".

Comment: then why onbackpressed exist here in doc.i donot think both will work same.it will call onkey down but backpressed will automatically call and will finish activity